# Как упорядочить массив по убыванию/возрастанию в Си? Используя только <stdio.h>

Tags: c, массивы

Как упорядочить массив по убыванию/возрастанию в Си?

Comment: Отсортировать с помощью [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

Comment: а не подключая stdlib?

Comment: Написать свою функцию сортировки.

Comment: а как её написать,?

Comment: Желательно самостоятельно:)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0%2bc?tab=Active

Comment: Реализовать понравившийся [алгоритм сортировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8#%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8) (я бы (по советам Кнута) рекомендовал [сортировку вставками](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8))

Answer (score 1):

Чисто для интереса. Вот функция [qsort от apple](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-166/stdlib.subproj/qsort.c.auto.html):

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1999 Apple Computer, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * @APPLE_LICENSE_HEADER_START@
 * 
 * The contents of this file constitute Original Code as defined in and
 * are subject to the Apple Public Source License Version 1.1 (the
 * "License").  You may not use this file except in compliance with the
 * License.  Please obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://www.apple.com/publicsource and read it before using this file.
 * 
 * This Original Code and all software distributed under the License are
 * distributed on an "AS IS" basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EITHER
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, AND APPLE HEREBY DISCLAIMS ALL SUCH WARRANTIES,
 * INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION, ANY WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE OR NON-INFRINGEMENT.  Please see the
 * License for the specific language governing rights and limitations
 * under the License.
 * 
 * @APPLE_LICENSE_HEADER_END@
 */
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1992, 1993
 *  The Regents of the University of California.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 3. All advertising materials mentioning features or use of this software
 *    must display the following acknowledgement:
 *  This product includes software developed by the University of
 *  California, Berkeley and its contributors.
 * 4. Neither the name of the University nor the names of its contributors
 *    may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
 *    without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE REGENTS AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE REGENTS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
 * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
 * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
 * OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
 * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY
 * OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
 * SUCH DAMAGE.
 */


#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline char  *med3 __P((char *, char *, char *, int (*)()));
static inline void   swapfunc __P((char *, char *, int, int));

#define min(a, b)   (a) < (b) ? a : b

/*
 * Qsort routine from Bentley & McIlroy's "Engineering a Sort Function".
 */
#define swapcode(TYPE, parmi, parmj, n) {       \
    long i = (n) / sizeof (TYPE);           \
    register TYPE *pi = (TYPE *) (parmi);       \
    register TYPE *pj = (TYPE *) (parmj);       \
    do {                        \
        register TYPE   t = *pi;        \
        *pi++ = *pj;                \
        *pj++ = t;              \
        } while (--i > 0);              \
}

#define SWAPINIT(a, es) swaptype = ((char *)a - (char *)0) % sizeof(long) || \
    es % sizeof(long) ? 2 : es == sizeof(long)? 0 : 1;

static inline void
swapfunc(a, b, n, swaptype)
    char *a, *b;
    int n, swaptype;
{
    if(swaptype <= 1) 
        swapcode(long, a, b, n)
    else
        swapcode(char, a, b, n)
}

#define swap(a, b)                  \
    if (swaptype == 0) {                \
        long t = *(long *)(a);          \
        *(long *)(a) = *(long *)(b);        \
        *(long *)(b) = t;           \
    } else                      \
        swapfunc(a, b, es, swaptype)

#define vecswap(a, b, n)    if ((n) > 0) swapfunc(a, b, n, swaptype)

static inline char *
med3(a, b, c, cmp)
    char *a, *b, *c;
    int (*cmp)();
{
    return cmp(a, b) < 0 ?
           (cmp(b, c) < 0 ? b : (cmp(a, c) < 0 ? c : a ))
              :(cmp(b, c) > 0 ? b : (cmp(a, c) < 0 ? a : c ));
}

void
qsort(a, n, es, cmp)
    void *a;
    size_t n, es;
    int (*cmp)();
{
    char *pa, *pb, *pc, *pd, *pl, *pm, *pn;
    int d, r, swaptype, swap_cnt;

loop:   SWAPINIT(a, es);
    swap_cnt = 0;
    if (n < 7) {
        for (pm = a + es; pm < (char *) a + n * es; pm += es)
            for (pl = pm; pl > (char *) a && cmp(pl - es, pl) > 0;
                 pl -= es)
                swap(pl, pl - es);
        return;
    }
    pm = a + (n / 2) * es;
    if (n > 7) {
        pl = a;
        pn = a + (n - 1) * es;
        if (n > 40) {
            d = (n / 8) * es;
            pl = med3(pl, pl + d, pl + 2 * d, cmp);
            pm = med3(pm - d, pm, pm + d, cmp);
            pn = med3(pn - 2 * d, pn - d, pn, cmp);
        }
        pm = med3(pl, pm, pn, cmp);
    }
    swap(a, pm);
    pa = pb = a + es;

    pc = pd = a + (n - 1) * es;
    for (;;) {
        while (pb <= pc && (r = cmp(pb, a)) <= 0) {
            if (r == 0) {
                swap_cnt = 1;
                swap(pa, pb);
                pa += es;
            }
            pb += es;
        }
        while (pb <= pc && (r = cmp(pc, a)) >= 0) {
            if (r == 0) {
                swap_cnt = 1;
                swap(pc, pd);
                pd -= es;
            }
            pc -= es;
        }
        if (pb > pc)
            break;
        swap(pb, pc);
        swap_cnt = 1;
        pb += es;
        pc -= es;
    }
    if (swap_cnt == 0) {  /* Switch to insertion sort */
        for (pm = a + es; pm < (char *) a + n * es; pm += es)
            for (pl = pm; pl > (char *) a && cmp(pl - es, pl) > 0; 
                 pl -= es)
                swap(pl, pl - es);
        return;
    }

    pn = a + n * es;
    r = min(pa - (char *)a, pb - pa);
    vecswap(a, pb - r, r);
    r = min(pd - pc, pn - pd - es);
    vecswap(pb, pn - r, r);
    if ((r = pb - pa) > es)
        qsort(a, r / es, es, cmp);
    if ((r = pd - pc) > es) { 
        /* Iterate rather than recurse to save stack space */
        a = pn - r;
        n = r / es;
        goto loop;
    }
/*      qsort(pn - r, r / es, es, cmp);*/
}
```

Comment: Интересно, эта лицензия(их там две) не конфликтует с местным CC BY-SA? =)

Comment: @vp_arth Не знаю.